# Scala String vs java.lang.String - type inference

Tags: string, scala, types, type-inference

In the REPL, I define a function. Note the return type.

```
scala> def next(i: List[String]) =  i.map {"0" + _} ::: i.reverse.map {"1" + _}
next: (i: List[String])List[java.lang.String]
```

And if I specify the return type as String

```
scala> def next(i: List[String]): List[String] = i.map {"0" + _} ::: i.reverse.map {"1" + _}
next: (i: List[String])List[String]
```

Why the difference? I can also specify the return type as List[Any], so I guess String is just a wrapper supertype to java.lang.String. Will this have any practical implications or can I safely not specify the return type?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is a very good question! First, let me assure you that you can safely specify the return type.

Now, let's look into it... yes, when left to inference, Scala infers `java.lang.String`, instead of just `String`. So, if you look up "String" in the [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html), you won't find anything, which seems to indicate it is not a Scala class either. Well, it has to come from someplace, though.

Let's consider what Scala imports by default. You can find it by yourself on the REPL:

```
scala> :imports
 1) import java.lang._             (155 types, 160 terms)
 2) import scala._                 (801 types, 809 terms)
 3) import scala.Predef._          (16 types, 167 terms, 96 are implicit)
```

The first two are packages -- and, indeed, `String` can be found on `java.lang`! Is that it, then? Let's check by instantiating something else from that package:

```
scala> val s: StringBuffer = new StringBuffer
s: java.lang.StringBuffer =

scala> val s: String = new String
s: String = ""
```

So, that doesn't seem to be it. Now, it can't be inside the `scala` package, or it would have been found when looking up on the ScalaDoc. So let's look inside [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Predef%24), and there it is!

```
type String = String
```

That means `String` is an *alias* for `java.lang.String` (which was imported previously). That looks like a cyclic reference though, but if you check the [source](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src//library/scala/Predef.scala#L1), you'll see it is defined with the full path:

```
type String        = java.lang.String
```

Next, you might want to ask *why?* Well, I don't have any idea, but I suspect it is to make such an important class a little less dependent on the JVM.

Comment: It's a bit of an oddity that string literals are inferred to be of type java.lang.String, when it seems they could equally well be be inferred to be of type String. But nice to know they are exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Luigi That's because the literals _are_ of type java.lang.String. There's really no inference here -- they are literals.