# wired scala type design

Tags: java, scala

my env is :

Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).

watch this example first:

```
scala> var a = 1
a: Int = 1

scala> var c = 'c
c: Symbol = 'c

scala> var d = 1.1
d: Double = 1.1

scala> var b = "123"
b: java.lang.String = 123

scala> val e:String = "234"
e: String = 234
```

so, you can see the other literal except string, the default type are Scala Types(`Int Double Symbol`.

but the string literal is Java type.(`java.lang.String`

and when you define a value with the scala type `String`, the String literal will be the type Scala String.

why the string literal's default type isn't Scala String?

Second:

when you must call scala method from java.

and your scala method with Parameter like this:

```
def hello(i:Int) = {
    println(i)
}
```

on java side . if you call like this.

object.hello(null)

it will fail by type mismatch.

the `java.lang.Integer` can be null. but the scala `Int` can't be null.

null in scala is the subtype of AnyRef. not AnyVal..

i found that AnyRef and AnyVal take me to the java1.4 world, which dose not have autobox.. .

Comment: can you please make your questions more specific. Could you clarify your questions please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala String vs java.lang.String - type inference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559938/scala-string-vs-java-lang-string-type-inference)

Comment: Please, if you have two questions, make two questions. And try to make the subjects more close to the question -- if you did that, Stack Overflow would have shown you the question for which your first question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer to your first question:

`scala.String` is simply a type synonym defined in <strike>`Prelude`</strike> `Predef` for good old `java.lang.String`. (Unlike `scala.Int`, `scala.Float` etc. which are distinct types from `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Float` etc.)

This might help: (Observe the types.)

```
scala> def f(s: String) = s * 2
f: (s: String)String

scala> f("hello")
res7: String = hellohello

scala> def f(s: String): java.lang.String = s * 2
f: (s: String)java.lang.String

scala> f("hello")
res8: java.lang.String = hellohello

scala> type Str = String
defined type alias Str

scala> def f(s: String): Str = s * 2
f: (s: String)Str

scala> f("hello")
res9: Str = hellohello
```

Comment: You probably mean `Predef` instead of `Prelude` :-)

Answer (score 6):

missingfaktor has answered the first question you have.

For the second part of your question: Scala.Int is different to java.lang.Integer, it is really an alias for a java int, and has pretty much the same behaviour:

```
scala> def print(i: Int) = println(i + " class=" + i.getClass.getName)
print: (i: Int)Unit
scala> print(43)
43 class=int
```

So scala treats scala.Int as int where possible. Note that autoboxing/unboxing occurs as normal.

```
scala> print(new java.lang.Integer(666))
666 class=int
```

So actually, it does not make sense to pass a null to a method which is expecting an int. This is a compilation error in Java as well.

```
private void setInt(int i) {}
setInt(null); // compilation error
```

If you force a null java.lang.Integer to be passed where an int is expected, then you get a NullPointerException. This is exactly the same behaviour as Java.

```
scala> val f: java.lang.Integer = null
f: java.lang.Integer = null
scala> print(f)
java.lang.NullPointerException
....
```

If you want to create a scala method which takes a nullable object, declare it to take java.lang.Integer. The autoboxing/unboxing behaviour will be exactly the same as for Java.

```
scala> def print(i: java.lang.Integer) = println(i + " class=" + i.getClass.getName)
print: (i: java.lang.Integer)Unit
scala> print(43)
43 class=java.lang.Integer
scala> print(new java.lang.Integer(666))
666 class=java.lang.Integer
```