# Scala returns different types for very similar expressions

Tags: java, scala, expression

If I evaluate the following expression in Scala REPL:

```
scala> "1" + 1
res0: java.lang.String = 11
```

the returned type is: **java.lang.String**.

If I evaluate this similar expression:

```
scala> 1 + "1"
res1: String = 11
```

the returned type is: **String**.

Why the difference?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559938/scala-string-vs-java-lang-string-type-inference

Comment: Both return `String` in Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference, however it is also not a bug. In this case:

```
"1" + 1
```

you are using built-in feature of Java to concatenate anything into a String. After all, many people convert numbers to strings using the following "idiom":

```
String s = "" + 5;
```

It works in Scala as well and results with `java.lang.String` - same as in Java.

On the other hand:

```
1 + "1"
```

is a bit more complex. This is translated into:

```
1.+("1")
```

and the `+()` method is taken from `Int.+` method located in `Int.scala`:

```
final class Int extends AnyVal {
    //....
    def +(x: String): String = sys.error("stub")
```

The `String` in this context is defined in `Predef.scala`:

```
type String        = java.lang.String
```

which is the source of the type "*difference*". As you can see both strings are in fact the same type.

Answer (score 2):

`"1"+1` invokes java.lang.String's operator+, `1+"1"` invokes an operator+ defined by the scala runtime (can't find it right now), so it returns a scala string.