# Overriding java method with arg of type java.util.Map[String, String] in scala class

Tags: java, scala, interop, overriding

I have an abstract class, written in Java:

```
abstract class AbstractJavaClass {
  abstract public Map<String, String> method(Map<String, String> params);
}
```

I'm trying to extend this class in scala:

```
class ScalaConcreteClass extends AbstractJavaClass {
  override def method(params: ...): ...
}
```

First I've written type (...) in scala as Map[String, String] (just didn't know what to try else :)), but it says: `(Note that java.util.Map[java.lang.String,java.lang.String] does not match Map[String,String])`

How should I override that methods?

Comment: `params: java.util.Map[String, String]` does not work? BTW your `AbstractJavaClass` uses Scala syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559938/scala-string-vs-java-lang-string-type-inference). I think you want to write `Map[java.lang.String, java.lang.String]`(or even `java.util.Map[java.lang.String, java.lang.String]`) (as the compiler says, actually).

Comment: Thanks, seems question is pretty lame, and solution is obvious, works in reduced form also: `java.util.Map[String, String]`