# Why is String different than Int,Boolean,Byte... in scala?

Tags: scala

Because I know a little bit Java I was trying to use in every Scala Code some Java types like `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Character`, `java.lang.Boolean` ... and so on. Now people told me "No! For everything in Scala there is an own type, the Java stuff will work - but you should always prefer the Scala types and objects".

Ok now I see, there is everything in Scala that is in Java. Not sure why it is better to use for example Scala Boolean instead of Java Boolean, but fine. If I look at the types I see `scala.Boolean`, `scala.Int`, `scala.Byte` ... and then I look at String but its not `scala.String`, (well its not even `java.lang.String` *confuse*) its just a String. But I thought I should use everything that comes direct from scala. Maybe I do not understand scala correctly, could somebody explain it please?

Comment: May be this topic will help you to understand this moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559938/scala-string-vs-java-lang-string-type-inference

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, 'well its not even java.lang.String' statement is not quite correct. Plain `String` name comes from type alias defined in `Predef` object:

```
type String = java.lang.String
```

and insides of `Predef` are imported in every Scala source, hence you use `String` instead of full `java.lang.String`, but in fact they are the same.

`java.lang.String` is very special class treated by JVM in special way. As @pagoda_5b said, it is declared as `final`, it is not possible to extend it (and this is good in fact), so Scala library provides a wrapper (`RichString`) with additional operations and an implicit conversion `String -> RichString` available by default.

However, there is slightly different situation with `Integer`, `Character`, `Boolean` etc. You see, even though `String` is treated specially by JVM, it still a plain class whose instances are plain objects. Semantically it is not different from, say, `List` class.
There is another situation with primitive types. Java `int`, `char`, `boolean` types are not classes, and values of these types are not objects. But Scala is fully object-oriented language, there are no primitive types. It would be possible to use `java.lang.{Integer,Boolean,...}` everywhere where you need corresponding types, but this would be awfully inefficient because of boxing.
Because of this Scala needed a way to present Java primitive types in object-oriented setting, and so `scala.{Int,Boolean,...}` classes were introduced. These types are treated specially via Scala compiler - scalac generates code working with primitives when it encounters one of these classes. They also extend `AnyVal` class, which prevents you from using `null` as a value for these types. This approach solves the problem with efficiency, leaves `java.lang.{Integer,Boolean,...}` classes available where you really need boxing, and also provides elegant way to use primitives of another host system (e.g. .NET runtime).

Answer (score 4):

I'm just guessing here

If you look at the docs, you can see that the scala version of primitives gives you all the expected operators that works on numeric types, or boolean types, and sensible conversions, without resorting to boxing-unboxing as for `java.lang` wrappers.

I think this choice was made to give uniform and natural access to what was expected of primitive types, while at the same time making them `Objects` as any other scala type.

I suppose that `java.lang.String` required a different approach, being an `Object` already, and `final` in its implementation. So the "path of least pain" was to create an implicit Rich wrapper around it to get missing operations on String, while leaving the rest untouched.

To see it another way, `java.lang.String` was already good enough as-is, being immutable and what-else.

It's worth mentioning that the other "primitive" types in scala have their own Rich wrappers that provides additional sensible operations.