# Rabbit Hole: found String, required java.lang.String

Tags: scala, type-signature, predef

Hit a really strange issue today while trying to add an implicit method to Either.

```
implicit class EitherProvidesRollback[String,B](e: Either[String,B]) {
  def rollback(
    ss: Option[Session], overrideMsg: Option[String]): Either[String,B] = {

    e.fold(
      msg=> {
        ss.map(_.rollback)
        // found String required java.lang.String, FTW
        // Left(i18n(overrideMsg.getOrElse(msg)))

        // behold, the horrible hack
        Left(i18n(overrideMsg.getOrElse(msg).toString).asInstanceOf[String])
      },
      Right(_)
    )
  }
}
```

the i18n method takes a String, which AFAICT is exactly what it's getting. The workaround, as [per this thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/9434.html), is to `T <: String` in the implicit class' type signature. It appears [Predef might be at play here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560090/185840).

Is there a way to get this working without horrendous runtime casting while at the same time preserving the type signature as exactly String?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two types called `String` in your code. One is `java.lang.String`, the other is the type parameter `String` that `EitherProvidesRollback` takes. I'm guessing using `String` as a type parameter to `EitherProvidesRollback` is your problem. It should only require `B` as its type parameter.