# Scala String type inference in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: string, scala, intellij-idea, type-inference

As far as I understand, in Scala

> `String` is an alias for `java.lang.String`

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560090/8762739), and can be seen in [Predef.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2420c258eb0e89f4f4aebf45d9ccd23521adfec7/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L134):

```
type String = java.lang.String
```

So essentially, they are the same.

However, in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5, the below code produces an error:

```
trait PerceptualHash {
  def calc[A](bi: BufferedImage): A
}

sealed trait BinaryStringPerceptualHash extends PerceptualHash {
  override def calc[String](bi: BufferedImage): String
}

private object GeneralBinaryStringPerceptualHash extends BinaryStringPerceptualHash {
  def calc[String](bi: BufferedImage): String = "0"
}
```

Here, `"0"` gets underlined with message "**Expression of type java.lang.String does not conform to expected type String**".

But if I change `"0"` like so:

```
def calc[String](bi: BufferedImage): String = new String("0")
```

then I get no such error message.

What's going on? Is it expected behaviour (and if so, why), am I doing something wrong, or rather it is a type inference bug in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signature for `calc` says that a `PerceptualHash` can convert a `BufferedImage` to any type the caller asks for. E.g. it's legal to do

```
GeneralBinaryStringPerceptualHash.calc[Int](image)
```

So `String` in

```
def calc[String](bi: BufferedImage): String = "0"
```

is just the name you gave to a parameter, unrelated to the standard `String` type. It is the same as

```
def calc[A](bi: BufferedImage): A = "0"
```

> But if I change "0" like so:
>
> ```
> def calc[String](bi: BufferedImage): String = new String("0")
> ```
>
> then I get no such error message.

You should get a different error message but you should still get one.

You *probably* want

```
trait PerceptualHash[A] {
  def calc(bi: BufferedImage): A
}

// calc is already def calc(bi: BufferedImage): String here, no need to override
sealed trait BinaryStringPerceptualHash extends PerceptualHash[String]
```

instead.

Comment: It is indeed what I want, thank you. And your comment about the uselessness of overriding `calc` in `BinaryStringPerceptualHash` blows my mind :-) Such is the power of type parameterisation.

Comment: I'd add that `BinaryStringPerceptualHash` is not itself particularly useful unless either 1) it has some shared code or 2) you need to test whether some `PerceptualHash` is a `BinaryStringPerceptualHash`.

Comment: You are right @AlexeyRomanov, I will only keep `BinaryStringPerceptualHash` with implementation and create class / object extending it.